# Sentry - settings for including JSON fields in quotation marks

Tags: sentry

The question here is as simple as it is: can I customize Sentry to take JSON fields into quotation marks?

[image]

So that

```
[{accessLevel: 0,....
```

becomes

```
[{"accessLevel": 0,....
```

Comment: Json properties are valid with or without quotes. This is just Sentry showing your what the request body looked like. These values were sent by the SDK to Sentry with the event, so that you can see what was the body. The values would appear like that whether the actual request body included quotes or not.

Comment: Bruno, I know that. The problem is that other environments (say, Postman, may not accept such format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Another way:

Open the event as JSON:

[image: JSON version of the event]

All the keys there are surrounded by quotes.

Original answer:

I see a couple ways to go:

Request a feature to get the keys wrapped or where a button toggles it on and off upon clicking. It can be requested to Sentry via the [issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues) or [the forum](https://forum.sentry.io).

Or simply copying the JSON and [pasting to a tool which adds the quotes for you](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html), before posting to whatever tool requires such formatting. I guess Postman in your case as you mentioned on the comment.

Or both, using the second until the feature gets implemented.